# jsf pages render <h:dataTable> slowly with larger number of html components

Tags: performance, jsf, rendering, myfaces, apache-tomee

My TomEE jsf project renders  as expected when running locally but renders extremely slowly when deployed remotely.

My remotely deployed jsf pages render  slowly when a relatively large number of components (relative to just displaying the template page with ) are the result of a call to data sources. Rendering times measure in minutes when there are more than just a few rows in the table.

Any ideas of where to look to isolate this problem?

Edit 2: I have deployed on multiple remote server environments. Rendering time of query results in `<dataTable>` seems to depend on bandwidth availability. Traveling to the physical location of the remote server, directly logging onto the remote server and accessing the application via localhost in any browser yields the result of nearly instantaneous rendering of the query results in the `<dataTable>` tag. Can it be that jsf is generating a huge html file size such that bandwidth becomes a constraint?

Edit 1: The first thing that I thought was that the remote server was doing a memory swaps from RAM to disk. It may be but that led me to make sure of checking the memory allocated to the JVM by TomEE in catalina.sh. See catalina.sh CATALINA_OPTS below.

I have found StackOverflow posts about logging being turned on/off for JSF but no reference of where this setting is. My logging.properties files seem to be identical remote and local for tomee's and the jvm's.

I also found posts about Mojarra's version of the API having an exponential time complexity but this project uses Apache MyFaces.

The problem seems to be some type of TomEE or JVM configuration issue. When I run the application on the locally installed version of TomEE, the same pages render in milliseconds.

I am using Apache MyFaces 2.1.13. From pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I'll gladly post the entire pom.xml but logic tells me that if the project renders pages at a different rate depending on the TomEE container that it is deployed in, then the issue is elsewhere.

Remote TomEE Configuration:
Tomcat Version  Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.53 (1.6.0.2)
JVM Version     1.7.0_55-mockbuild_2014_04_16_07_52-b00
JVM Vendor  Oracle Corporation
OS Name     Linux 
OS Version  2.6.18-371.8.1.el5
OS Architecture     amd64

Local Tomee Configuration:
Tomcat Version  Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.53 (1.6.0.2)
JVM Version     1.7.0_67-b01
JVM Vendor  Oracle Corporation
OS Name     Mac OS X 
OS Version  10.9.5
OS Architecture     x86_64

BalusC mentioned memory which is a good thought. From catalina.sh

```
    grep "CATALINA_OPTS=" -n /usr/share/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.6.0.2/bin/catalina.sh
272:  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"
```

And from system info:

```
#

 cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:      6969972 kB
MemFree:        128928 kB
Buffers:        349588 kB
Cached:        4895748 kB
SwapCached:         92 kB
Active:        1633928 kB
Inactive:      4416324 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:      6969972 kB
LowFree:        128928 kB
SwapTotal:    10027000 kB
SwapFree:     10025000 kB
Dirty:             144 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:      804828 kB
Mapped:          52836 kB
Slab:           752492 kB
PageTables:       8928 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  13511984 kB
Committed_AS:  1360596 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    267944 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359470039 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

Comment: How about memory? Mojarra's problem was fixed in 2.1.22 already by the way.

Comment: Ah, excellent thought Balus. Thank you. I'll edit the post with CATALINA_OPTS & system info.

Comment: _"Can it be that jsf is generating a huge html file size such that bandwidth becomes a constraint?"_ Try it, analyze it, check it, know it... And please, if you edit, put the info at the end and emphasize things!